# Open A pop window in spring

Tags: spring-mvc

i have controller through which it navigate to `home.jsp` in home .jsp there is two button `FindEmployeeByid` `FindEmployeeByName` now as i click on FindEmployeeByid new popup window is opened but in pop window i got this message `The requested resource (/EmployeeWebSpring/search/Search.jsp) is not available.` ,because in Search.jsp i have use form tag of spring so it does not able to get model object so plz tell how i can perform this to open a pop window with input fields active so that i can submit the data a perform some operation on that data

this is my controller

```
    package com.nousinfo.tutorial.controllers;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.validation.annotation.Validated;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import com.nousinfo.tutorial.model.EmployeeForm;
import com.nousinfo.tutorial.service.impl.EmployeeServiceImpl;
import com.nousinfo.tutorial.service.model.EmployeeBO;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/search")
public class SearchEmployeeController {

    private EmployeeServiceImpl employeeServiceImpl;

    public void setEmployeeServiceImpl(EmployeeServiceImpl employeeServiceImpl) {
        this.employeeServiceImpl = employeeServiceImpl;
    }



    @RequestMapping(value = "/searchspring", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String view(@Validated EmployeeForm employeeForm)
            throws Exception {
    return "home";
    }


    @RequestMapping(value = "/employeeNo", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView searchByEmpNo(
            @ModelAttribute("employeeForm") EmployeeForm employeeForm)
            throws Exception {
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
        model.addObject("employeeForm", employeeForm);
        Long i = Long.parseLong(employeeForm.getEmployeeNumber());

        EmployeeBO employeeBO = employeeServiceImpl.getEmployee(i);
        System.out.println(employeeBO);
        model.addObject("employeeBO", employeeBO);

        model.setViewName("EmployeeDetail");
        return model;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/empByName", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView searchByEmployeeName(
            @ModelAttribute("employeeForm") EmployeeForm employeeForm) {
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
        model.addObject("employeeForm", employeeForm);
        List<EmployeeBO> employeeBOs = employeeServiceImpl
                .findEmployees(employeeForm.getFirstName());
        model.addObject("listEmployeeBO", employeeBOs);
        model.setViewName("EmployeeList");
        return model;

    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/empByDeptId", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView searchByDeptId(
            @ModelAttribute("employeeForm") EmployeeForm employeeForm) {
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
        model.addObject("employeeForm", employeeForm);
        List<EmployeeBO> employeeBOs = employeeServiceImpl
                .getAllEmployeeByDeptid(employeeForm.getDepartmentId());
        model.addObject("listEmployeeBO", employeeBOs);
        model.setViewName("EmployeeList");

        return model;

    }

}
```

this is my home.jsp

```
  <%@page import="java.util.List"%>

<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" prefix="fmt"%>


<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css"></link>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" type="text/css"></link>
<title>Home</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function LoadByName(windowHeight, windowWidth) {
        var centerWidth = (window.screen.width - windowWidth) / 2;
        var centerHeight = (window.screen.height - windowHeight) / 2;
        newWindow = window.open('Search.jsp', 'mywindow',
                'resizable=0,width=' + windowWidth + ',height=' + windowHeight
                        + ',left=' + centerWidth + ',top=' + centerHeight);
        newWindow.divHiding(1);
        newWindow.focus();
    }
    function LoadById(windowHeight, windowWidth) {
        var centerWidth = (window.screen.width - windowWidth) / 2;
        var centerHeight = (window.screen.height - windowHeight) / 2;
        newWindow = window.open('Search.jsp', 'mywindow',
                'resizable=0,width=' + windowWidth + ',height=' + windowHeight
                        + ',left=' + centerWidth + ',top=' + centerHeight);
        newWindow.divHiding(2);
        newWindow.focus();
        return newWindow.name;
    }

    function loadName(name) {
        this.firstName = name;
        window.location = 'http://localhost:8080/EmployeeWebApp/GetEmployeeServlet?key1='
                + encodeURIComponent(firstName);
    }
    function loadId(id) {
        this.id = id;
        window.location = 'http://localhost:8080/EmployeeWebApp/GetEmployeeServlet?key2='
                + encodeURIComponent(id);
    }
</script>
</head>
<table width="951" height="116" border="0" align="center">
    <tr>
        <td width="961" height="112" align="center" bgcolor="#99CCFF"><h2>NOUS
                INFOSYSTEMS</h2></td>
        <td width="266" height="112" align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><img
            src="image/emps.jpg" alt="1" width="266" height="84" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>

<p>&nbsp;</p>
<table width="949" height="183" border="0" align="center">
    <tr>
        <td width="943" height="43"><input id="findid" name="button"
            type="submit" value="Find Employee By Number or ID"
            onClick="LoadById(250,500)" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td height="43"><input id="findname" name="submit2" type="button"
            value="Find Employee By Name" onClick="LoadByName(250,500)" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><form id="form2" action="get.spring" method="get">
                <input type="submit" name="submit3" value="Get All Employees" />
            </form></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><form id="form3" action="CreateEmployee.jsp">
                <input type="submit" name="submit3" value="Create An Employee" />
            </form></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<br>
<br>
<body>
    <form>
        <table width="725" border="1" align="center" cellpadding="5"
            cellspacing="5">
            <tr>
                <th width="118">EmployeeNumber</th>
                <th width="118">First Name</th>
                <th width="118">Last Name</th>
                <th width="118">Title</th>
                <th width="118">Address1</th>
                <th width="118">Address2</th>
                <th width="118">City</th>
                <th width="118">Details</th>
            </tr>
            <c:forEach var="employeeBO" items="${model.listEmployeeBO}">
                <tr>

                    <td>${employeeBO.employeeNumber}</td>

                    <td>${employeeBO.firstName}</td>

                    <td>${employeeBO.lastName}</td>

                    <td>${employeeBO.title}</td>

                    <td>${employeeBO.address1}</td>

                    <td>${employeeBO.address2}</td>

                    <td>${employeeBO.city}</td>


                </tr>
            </c:forEach>

        </table>
        <table>
            <tr>

                <td></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

and this is my search.jsp

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" prefix="fmt"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring"%>

<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>

<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" prefix="fn"%>


<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<fmt:setBundle basename="ApplicationResources" />
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Employee Search Page</title>

</head>
<body>
    <form:form action="/EmployeeWebSpring/search/empByName"  commandName="employeeForm" method="post">
        <table border="0">



            <tr>
                <td>Employee_ID</td>
                <td><form:input path="employeeNumber"  /></td>
                <td><input type="submit" name="method" value="FindById" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Employee_Name</td>
                <td><form:input path="firstName" /></td>
                <td><input type="submit" name="method" value="FindByName" /></td>
            </tr>


            <tr>
                <td>Employee_Name</td>
                <td><form:input path="departmentId" /></td>
                <td><input type="submit" name="method" value="FindByDeptNO" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" align="center"><font size=3>For
                        Searching the employees by<b>Employee Name</b><br />you can use %
                        match all the records with the given pattern
                </font><br /> <font size="2"> <i>e.g <b> for search by</b>EmployeeName<br />
                            matches alL the employees whose name starts with character <b>S</b></i></font></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form:form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: May be you can use javascript to submit the form, rather than a conventional form action.

Comment: @shazinltc problem is resolved no need of that but if u can plz tell means after successfully open a search.jsp in pop window now i have used div tag now based upon the button click i want to show the div tag i have java script but through this "newWindow = window.open('../search/searchPage', 'mywindow',)" and "newWindow.showDiv(1)" in search.jsp i m not able to get value of 1 why?

Comment: @henrycharles please if you've solved your problem post an answer to it so others could solve similar problems, regards.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do the following in java script and run your java script function as your function run it takes  control to controller ,their you can provide the jsp view or any view

```
<script>
    function popup() {
        window.open("../popup/searchspring", 'window', 'width=200,height=100');
    }
</script>
```

and in controller you have to do something like this which will navigate your request to desired page cause in spring controller decide the navigation of view pages

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/searchspring", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String view(Model model) throws Exception {
        EmployeeBO employeeBO = new EmployeeBO();
        model.addAttribute("employeeBO", employeeBO);
        return "EmployeeForm";
    }
```

Comment: a morning wasted on this topic... and this is the only truly answer. Well done!!!

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it in my Spring MVC Project by the following way:

The **Controller class** is like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "viewPicture.dispatch", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String viewPicture(HttpServletRequest request, RequestParam(value="fileName")String fileName, @RequestParam(value="filePath")String filePath) {

    //some code..

    return "viewDCPicture";   //the View where it will go.
}
```

The **JSP page** on which I have written JS and Html code also, is like this:

```
<script>
    function viewDCPicture(fileName){
        var filePath = $("#filePath").val();

        //Setting the left and right size of the pop-up window
        var left = (screen.width/2)-(1100/2);
        var top = (screen.height/2)-(170/2);

        $.ajax({
            method: "GET",
            url : "viewPicture.dispatch?fileName=" + fileName + "&filePath=" + filePath,
            success : function(response) {
                var strURL = "viewPicture.dispatch?fileName=" + fileName + "&filePath=" + filePath + "";
                window.open(strURL, 'viewDCPicture', 'width=1100, height=600, resizable=1, scrollbars=yes, location=0, status=0, titlebar=no, toolbar=0, addressbar=0, top='+top+', left='+left+'');
            },
            error : function(e) {
            }
        });
    }
</script>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td align="right"><label>SUPPORTING DOCS.</label></td>
        <c:forEach items="${attachmentDtlList}" var="data"> 
            <td>
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" title="Picture" onclick = "viewDCPicture('${data.key}');">${data.key}</a>
                <input type="hidden" id="filePath" value="${data.value}">
            </td>
        </c:forEach>
    </tr>
</table>
```

In my **template.xml** where the JSP files are mapped with the perticular `name = "viewDCPicture"`, I have made changes like this:

I have created a template inside the template.xml file as:

```
<definition name = "viewDocTemplate" template = "/viewDoc.jsp">
    <put-attribute name = "body" value = "" />
</definition>
```

And used it inside the temlate.xml file as:

```
<definition extends = "viewDocTemplate" name = "viewDCPicture">
    <put-attribute name = "body" value = "/enquiry_management/viewDCPicture.jsp" />
</definition>
```

The **viewDoc.jsp** file which will help the **Pop-up window** file **viewDCPicture.jsp** to bind it inside body of **viewDoc.jsp** is as follows:

```
<%@ page language = "java" contentType = "text/html; charset = UTF-8"
pageEncoding = "UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix = "c" uri = "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@ taglib uri = "http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles" prefix = "tiles"%>
<%@ taglib uri = "http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix = "spring"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset = "UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <%-- Adding spring attribute for adding body, header, footer etc tag. --%>
    <spring:htmlEscape defaultHtmlEscape = "true" />
    <tiles:insertAttribute name = "body" />
</body>
</html>
```

The **viewDCPicture.jsp** file is like this:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
    <table align="center" class="headingSpas">
        <tr>
            <td class="headingSpas">
                <table width="100%" align="center" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2" align="center" class="headingSpas" >
                            <img alt="" src="<%=path%>" border="0" align="top" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</html>
```